# How to add conditional schema based on other field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this structure:

```
{
    personFullName: String,
    personMobileOS: Number // 1 = IOS, 2 = Android,
    moreDetails: Mixed
}
```

I want to add conditional schema based on other field like this:

```
if (personMobileOS === 1) { // IOS
    moreDetails = { 
        iosVersion: Number, 
        loveApple: Boolean
    }
} else if (personMobileOS === 2) { // Android
    moreDetails = {
        wantToSell: Boolean,
        wantToSellPrice: Number
        wantToSellCurrency: Number // 1 = Dollar, 2 = Euro, 3 = Pound
    }
}
```

As you can see, the schema for "moreDetails" is conditional, it's possible to achieve this in mongoose?

Comment: See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-and-this

Comment: @str it's not enought for me because i want to be able to plug schema (and enjoy the benefits of mongoose schemas) instead of doing the validation by my self.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to create dynamic schemas the way you want it. So custom validation is your only option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not sure if it's too late for this but I think what you need is [mongoose subdocument discriminator](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1856). This allow you to have 2 different schema on subdocument, mongoose will take care of schema mapping, include the validation.

Yes, what you need to archive in this question is a long standing issue and has been requested since mongoose 3.0. And now it's official :)

An example with a new mongoose subdocument discriminator:

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({ message: String },
  { discriminatorKey: 'kind' });

const Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

const ClickedEvent = Event.discriminator('Clicked', new Schema({
  element: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}));

const PurchasedEvent = Event.discriminator('Purchased', new Schema({
  product: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}));
```

[Also checkout this blog post](http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-4.8-embedded-discriminators.html) for more details